# Given the offset of a word in a text file, the java program should retrieve respective line number

Tags: java

I need to extract the whole line in a text that a given offset belongs to. For example:

```
"Therapist: Okay. {Pause} 
So, how do you feel about -- about this -- about what's going on with your health? 

Participant: I don't like it. 
There's nothing I can do about it.
{Pause}

Therapist: Yeah.\

15-30-28-0140.raw

Therapist: That doesn't sound so good. 
A little bit stressful."
```

If I ask for the offsetNum=125 the output will be "Participant: I don't like it. "
As can be seen, empty lines should be considered.

I wrote the following code that works on some text files but screws up on some others (is unreliable):

```
 int offset = startingOffset;

                try (LineNumberReader r = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(Input))) {
                    int count = 0;

                    while (r.read() != -1 && count < offset)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (count == offset)
                    {

                          lineNo = r.getLineNumber()
                    }
```

However, I need a reliable way to get the actual line an not lineNo...

Comment: How is that not reliable?

Comment: Read the first `offset` bytes from the file (I assume it's a byte offset?). Then count the number of `'\n'` characters in those bytes.

Comment: To add on to what Andy said, I would count the number of `System.lineSeperator()` strings in the bytes to be more precise. It shouldn't cause issues, but it's good practice to use `System.lineSeperator()`.

Comment: @ext0 not necessarily. The file might have been written on a computer with a different line separator vs the one you are analyzing the file on; unless you're going to assume that the line separator contains a `'\n'` (which it almost certainly will if the file was written on a mainstream computer recently), you'd need to know the line separator symbol explicitly.

Comment: @AndyTurner Likewise, the file may have been written on a computer that's not a Linux/Windows machine. The only way to prevent any issues at all is to split on occurrences of `\r`, `\n`, and `\r\n`,

Comment: @ext0 which is why I say "you'd need to know the line separator symbol explicitly".

Comment: @Andy Turner By offset I mean the number of characters from the beginning.

Comment: So multi-byte characters (e.g. for UTF-8 encoding) only counts a 1 character? Newlines count as 2 (`\r\n`) or 1 (`\n`) depending on what's actually *in* the file? Surrogate pairs counts as 1 or 2? Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method will do what you want.

It counts every character, including `CR` and `LF` characters, building up a line of text in the `line` buffer. At end of each line, it checks if `offsetNum` was within that line, including first character and newline character, and returns line if it was. Otherwise it clears the `line` buffer and continue for next line.

Note that if `offsetNum` is on the `LF` of a `CRLF` pair, it will return an empty line, which isn't correct, but I'll let you figure that one out.

```
private static String readLineAtOffset(String fileName, int offsetNum) throws IOException {
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        for (int ch; (ch = reader.read()) != -1; count++) {
            if (ch != '\r' && ch != '\n')
                line.append((char)ch);
            else if (count < offsetNum)
                line.setLength(0);
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    return (count >= offsetNum ? line.toString() : null);
}
```

Comment: How about if we need the LineNo?

Comment: Add another counter and increment for each line.